# Lattice in noncompact simple group is Ad-irreducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Is every lattice in a Lie group Ad-irreducible?

No. This is false for $ G $ compact because any finite subgroup is a lattice. And it is certainly false if $ G $ is not simple since a group can only contain an Ad-irreducible subgroup if it is itself simple. So I'm asking...

**Is every lattice in a non compact simple Lie group Ad-irreducible?**

In other words, let $ G $ be a non compact simple Lie group. Let $ \Gamma $ be a lattice in $ G $. Must the the conjugation action of $ \Gamma $ on the lie algebra of $ G $ be an irreducible representation?

For example, I think it is true that all lattices in $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $  are Ad-irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired fact follows from a Borel density theorem type result. Thm 3 of

[https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/BorelDensity.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/BorelDensity.pdf)

states "Let G be a connected semisimple $\mathbb{R}$-algebraic group and let Γ < G
be a lattice. Let ϕ : G → $GL_m(\mathbb{R})$ be an irreducible polynomial representation
of G. Then the restriction of ϕ to Γ is irreducible." (this theorem should also assume that $ G $ has no compact factors, but that is sort of implied by context, for example theorem 1 earlier in the reference specifies that $ G $ has no compact factors)

Every noncompact simple Lie group, other than the universal cover of $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $, is a connected semisimple $\mathbb{R}$-algebraic group. For a simple group the adjoint representation is irreducible by definition. Also the adjoint representation is always a polynomial representation. Thus we can apply the theorem to conclude that the adjoint representation restricted to $ \Gamma $ must be irreducible.

The last case to consider is when $ G $ is not algebraic because it is the universal cover of $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $. In this case the adjoint representation still factors through actual $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ and any lattice $ \tilde{\Gamma} $ in the universal cover factors through a lattice $ \Gamma $ in actual $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $. So the result is also true for all lattices in the universal cover of $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $.